# Automatically start a program (Sphinx searchd) when server is restarted?

Tags: linux, centos, sphinx

When my server (running CENTOS) is restarted I have to manually start searchd for each website I use Sphinx on.

It's not hard to do (just copy/paste one line in the terminal for each site), but if I forget to do it, or am not aware that the server has been restarted, then search will be down
on my websites.

The command I'm referring to to start searchd is this:

```
/usr/local/bin/searchd --config /path/to/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf
```

Is there a way to have searchd automatically start up when my server is restarted?

Comment: Modify the apache start/stop scripts to also start/stop sphinx?

Comment: searchd is part of Sphinx, not of Apache, so is a separate service. You shouldn't need to restart it when restarting Apache. To ensure that the service is running, add rather your above command to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: @harrymc I think you are right. I'm changing my question.

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using? This is important to know because CentOS 7 uses systemd for system startup.

Comment: @FSMaxB I have version 6.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure Sphinx to start automatically, start by adding the `searchd` start command to the server `rc.local` file :

```
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

Paste the following code just above the `exit 0` line :

```
/usr/bin/searchd --config /var/www/yoursitecom/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf
```

Now that everything is setup and running, to make sure that the index stays up-to-date with the database, run a crontab to rotate (rebuild) the index every 6 hours :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add the following line to the bottom of the document.

```
0 */6 * * * /usr/bin/indexer --rotate --config /var/www/yoursitecom/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf --all
```

Source :
[Working with Sphinx (Search Engine) on a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP) Stack Server](http://atlchris.com/1996/working-with-sphinx-search-engine-on-a-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-and-php-stack-server/).

Answer (score 7):

in my case (Debian 8.9)

```
  /usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf
```

does not start sphinx and instead I need to run

```
  sudo service sphinxsearch start
```

to get sphinx started

The answer from harrymc pointed me to the right solution and when I edited

```
  sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and included

```
  sudo service sphinxsearch start
```

just before the exit 0 line, then it finally loaded sphinx upon reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using something like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It is not as simple as using `/etc/rc.local` and it require some configuration but it gives more flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

In my case works this:

in `/etc/rc.local`

I added line: `service searchd start`